# File Open and Exception

Tags: php-5.3

does file related functions throw an exception when it fails OR just return false.
Coz even if I use it in try-catch, there is no point in catching an exception if fopen/fwrite does not throw it at all…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Return Values**

Returns a file pointer resource on success, or FALSE on error.

**Errors/Exceptions**

If the open fails, an error of level E_WARNING is generated. You may use @ to suppress this warning.

[Check documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). you can throw custom exception if you want to.